# Difference between "perl" and "perl -w"?

Tags: perl

I am learning Perl , very new user . May i know whats the difference between these Perl codes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

&

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
```

Comment: I rolled back your edit, as it is not customary to fix your question after the answer is given. It makes the answers look rather odd.

Comment: @TLP Thank you ,from you  i just got know what to call them .

Comment: Just as an esoteric note, if someone has set PERL5OPT, there might be no difference.

Comment: Also, you probably want `#!/usr/bin/env perl` (and not `#!/usr/bin/perl`). This is especially important on boxes like CentOS 5, where a newer PERL may be installed in `/usr/local`. Or maybe OS X with a MacPorts installation and PERL located in `/opt/local/bin`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is not perl code, it's a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), which is used in a linux/unix environment as a way to tell the shell what program should be used to run the program file. It has no effect in windows, but it does activate any switches used.

The `-w` part is a switch for perl, telling it to activate warnings. You can learn more about perl's command line switches by typing `perl -h` at the command prompt. Read more in [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

`-w` is the older version of the `use warnings` pragma, which is preferred nowadays. While `-w` is global, `use warnings` is lexical, and can be activated selectively.

Comment: Thank you for the answer . Now I have a doubt that , up to how much extent these -w can helps us ? Warnings means  what kind of ?

Comment: @August Warnings are there to, well, warn you of potential problem spots in your code where errors can easily occur. It's good practice to not only get the errors fixed, but have no warnings as well.

Comment: Is it better to `use warnings`?

Comment: @squiguy Yes, because you can select specific errors you want, or can silence errors you don't want e.g. `no warnings 'redefine'` if you want to redefine a sub.

Comment: @amon That's what I have heard, so I thought I would add a little to the answer for the poster.

Comment: @August Using `use strict; use warnings;` and learning how to deal with warnings/errors will help you more than any single other thing you can do while coding perl. Not using warnings will allow errors to happen silently, leaving you with no clue what is wrong.

Comment: @TLP I think now i am getting slowly , you mean if warnings are silent means in future there will be a chance to bugs rise right ?

Comment: @sidran32 Yeah now i am getting it , the real need of them . Thank you .

Comment: @August Hidden bugs is only one of the many things `warnings` helps prevent. Try for example: `perl -e 'print "True" if "a" == "b"'`. Then add `-w` to spot the error.

Comment: Note `-w` flag affects whole interpreter context, so if some other module you use will produce a warning, it will be no way to disable it cus whole interpreter is in warning mode. As opposite, `use warnings;` enables warnings only in current module. Plus, it is strongly recommended to do `use strict;` in every script/module.

Comment: @PSIAlt Like I said: "While -w is global, use warnings is lexical, and can be activated selectively."