# How to use two CPAN modules in a script

Tags: linux, perl, ssh

Here I'm trying to use two CPAN modules in a script. Is there a proper way to use other than what I've used in my code?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$host='example/cp,';
$user='usertest';
$pass='kjasdkjd';
$cmd='su -';
$stdin='jkhasdj';
#$cmd='passwd';
use Net::SSH::Perl;
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("$host", options => [
"use_pty 1", "interactive true"]);
$ssh->login($user, $pass);
#my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd,[$stdin]);
#$ssh->shell;
#print ("$stdout\n");
#print ("$stderr\n");
#print ("$exit\n");

use Net::SSH::Expect;
$ssh->send("passwd");
$ssh->waitfor('password:\s*\z', 1) or die "prompt 'password' not found after 1 second";
$ssh->send("frghthhyj");
$ssh->waitfor(':\s*\z', 1) or die "prompt 'New password:' not found";
$ssh->send("redhat");
$ssh->waitfor(':\s*\z', 1) or die "prompt 'Confirm new password:' not found";
$ssh->send("redhat");
```

I'm getting error `"Can't locate object method "send" via package "Net::SSH::Perl::SSH2"` though the "send" method is associated with "Net::SSH::Expect" the script looks for the method in "Net::SSH::Perl" which is not correct.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do here. You cannot bless a single reference by two packages simultaneously, and that makes sense - how can a single object belong to two different classes at the same time?

Comment: Basically  I'm trying to ssh in to remote machine using perl, also I need to su to root to gain root access on the remote machine. "my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd,[$stdin])" associated with Net::SSH::Perl is not working, hence wanted to utilize the method "send" of Net::SSH::Expect. Before trying this I wanted to check the functionality of Net::SSH::Expect, so used the default code available in the official page. I'm a newbie in perl, so not sure whether this can be done or not. Kindly advise.

Comment: You can login using Net::SSH::Expect, please go through the manpage.

Comment: Hey Karthik, you should at the very least start your perl script with 

use strict;
use warnings;

see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12554195/1702521 for the diff between "-w" and "use warnings"

Answer (score 2):

Look at the documentation for [`Net::SSH::Expect`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-SSH-Expect/lib/Net/SSH/Expect.pod).  It shows how to create an instance of the object, login, etc.

You can't login via [`Net::SSH::Perl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aPerl) and magically convert your instance `$ssh` into an Expect object.  Just start with Expect from the very beginning.

Comment: Thanks, Miller. problem is that I couldn't find an alternate for method "$ssh->shell" which is avaialable in Net::SSH::Perl. I need to replace the SSH client using this script along with login automation.